# Instagram bot: how do I make sure the bot does not unlike already liked photos?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, bots, instagram

I am trying to build an instagram bot that can follow profiles, and like and comment on posts. The relevant part of the code that controls the "like" process is below. It works, but if the photo opened is already liked, the bot clicks on the like again, effectively unliking it. How do I prevent this?

```
try:
    button_like = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button')                  
    button_like.click()
    likes += 1
    sleep(randint(18,25))
except Exception:
    print("An error occurred when trying to like images")
```

The XPATH is the same for the like button, regardless of whether its already liked or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether an image is already liked or not by checking **attribute value** of area-label as it gets changed from **Like** :

```
<svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
```

To **Unlike**:

```
<svg aria-label="Unlike" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#ed4956" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
```

so you can check weather an image is already liked or not by checking the value of the attribute before performing click.